# Install PHP 5.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS without Compiling

Tags: 14.04, apt, php

`ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable` does not support PHP 5.4 for Ubuntu 13.10 and higher. There seems to be no official or a stable way to install PHP 5.4 instead of 5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS currently. I've seen most answers on StackOverflow/Exchange but in the end, they are mostly all outdated.

How can I install `PHP 5.4` on `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` directly from a repository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downgrade PHP Version from 5.5 to 5.4 on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/455614/downgrade-php-version-from-5-5-to-5-4-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen It is not. The answer refers to http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-ubuntu-12.04 which is based on Ubuntu 12.04 plus, it is instructions to DOWNGRADE to `Apache+fcgid+php5.4` - I do not have anything installed yet and do not need fcgid.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I also ran into issues following that answer you pointed out.

Comment: What "issues"? and the question is " Downgrade PHP Version from 5.5 to 5.4 on Ubuntu 14.04" so it applies to 14.04

Comment: @bodhi.zazen it ended up installing PHP 5.3 - and I do not need to 'Downgrade' as there is no PHP installed to start off with.

Comment: there is also the option to use phpbrew ... you need to provide more information.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I was successful in using phpbrew just now to install PHP 5.4.34 - I'll provide the steps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18698/discussion-between-francis-kim-and-bodhi-zazen).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Install requirements for phpbrew

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get build-dep php5
apt-get install -y php5 php5-dev php-pear autoconf automake curl build-essential libxslt1-dev re2c libxml2 libxml2-dev php5-cli bison libbz2-dev libreadline-dev
apt-get install -y libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev libpng12-0 libpng12-dev libjpeg-dev libjpeg8-dev libjpeg8  libgd-dev libgd3 libxpm4 libltdl7 libltdl-dev
apt-get install -y libssl-dev openssl
apt-get install -y gettext libgettextpo-dev libgettextpo0
apt-get install -y php5-cli
apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev
apt-get install libicu-dev
```

#### Install phpbrew

```
curl -L -O https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/raw/master/phpbrew
chmod +x phpbrew
sudo mv phpbrew /usr/bin/phpbrew
```

#### Initialise phpbrew, update and install PHP 5.4

```
phpbrew init
phpbrew known --update
phpbrew update
```

Here we choose PHP 5.4.34, but you can change this to any version that is available as listed by the above commands - like 5.5.22.

```
phpbrew install 5.4.34 +default
```

#### Update your shell config file by adding the following to the end of your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` *(basically the shell you're using, default to .bashrc)*

```
source ~/.phpbrew/bashrc
```

Close your terminal to take effect, and restart it.

#### Switch the default PHP version to 5.4

```
phpbrew switch php-5.4.34
```

If it shows `Invalid Argument`, try `phpbrew switch 5.4.34` instead.

#### Check your PHP version

```
php -v
```

Comment: You should run the install command as `phpbrew install -j N 5.4.34 +default` where N is the max number of CPU cores for compiling.  That way your hugely wide multi-core system is put to more use and finishes faster.

Comment: I completed everything as root (even restarting apache2 and php5-fpm services), but my web server still reports that it's running php 5.5.  What am I missing?

Comment: @jbo5112 `phpbrew switch php-5.4.34` should do the trick if the previous steps were ok.

Comment: I've run `phpbrew switch php-5.4.38` (current version I compiled), restarted apache2 and php5-fpm, and checked the output of `phpinfo()` in my web server.  Just running `php -v` works fine, but the web server still says "PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6".  I assume I still have to update some system config file for php5-fpm.

Comment: For using php fpm, I needed to shut down the system php5-fpm `service php5-fpm stop` and then run `phpbrew fpm start`.

Comment: for me one thing was missing here:

    apt-get install libicu-dev

I got an error when trying to install a php version and the log said:

configure: error: Unable to detect ICU prefix or no failed. Please verify ICU install prefix and make sure icu-config works.

Comment: Had to also install `libreadline-dev` and `libmcrypt-dev`

Comment: Also had to add `source ~/.phpbrew/bashrc` to the end of `~/.bashrc`, otherwise it would not switch

Comment: You rock but getting error if I try to install php-5.5.0 (404 Not Found) because php-5.5.0.tar.gz not found in  www.php.net/get/....;  Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If it shows Invalid Argument, try over and over again nothing, the only thing that help is these two line and in this order:

```
source ~/.phpbrew/bashrc && phpbrew list
phpbrew switch 5.4.45
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your answer may be a bit late as the OP already accepted the other answer. Your help is of course appreciated, however you might be better served by focusing your efforts on the [unanswered questions](//askubuntu.com/unanswered)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `phpbrew` is located in:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

not

```
/usr/bin
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** you *can* edit existing answers to improve them.  2 reviewers will review your edits and approve if deemed useful!  (I would!)  **;-)**